# Running an ionic app inside ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view, ionic-native

Is there any way to develop the main app with logins using ionic and develop subparts of that app as individual apps and use the main app to access the sub-apps and pass the login info to sub apps.

Draw.io Flow Diagram For Better idea [1](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Untitled%20Diagram.html#R7VjBcpswFPwajumAhDE%2BOiRuO9OcfGh7VNAD1MiIyiLG%2FfpKIAIEnGQmZZxOgscG7XsS0r5dRsbB0a76LEmR3QgK3EEurRx85SCEXLzUJ4McG8Rzfb9BUsmoxTpgy%2F5Am2jRklHYDxKVEFyxYgjGIs8hVgOMSCkOw7RE8OFdC5LCCNjGhI%2FR74yqrEHDhdvhX4ClWXtnz7WRWxLfpVKUub2fg3BSH014R9qxbP4%2BI1QcehC%2BdnAkhVDN1a6KgBtyW9qafpsT0Yd5S8jVSzr4KESLZejFwSpxl8S%2FQM0I94SX0C6hnqg6tuTUywMzgOvgy0PGFGwLEpvoQetBY5nacd3y9CUl%2B6zONY29kuIOIsGFrIfCQRzCbaIjCeO8h1MCYRIbXOSqh2%2FW5qNxO0uQCqqTS%2FceCNVKBbEDJY86xXZoi2k1urLNQ1dvFFgs69Xab0tNrMbSh5E7nvWFpfqFtHtjmoFqSdqmkCoTqcgJv%2B7Qy2EheqRDxdQPA39a2NZPG%2FkFSh2t30iphIa6sb8JUdi8p3k3U3uadb0SUcoYTiwXW08TmYI6RYk7XT4JnCh2P5zAPy0Gft4Dz6ie7IvmsZSwyhToORuswmizGdsgcr2rKNJ4Kgll0JUkFznM647l0B2eN7ZHOOGOcBZz4DnM4fWs0RjljZjDf4E5gnN5w%2F%2FwBvLCN2SOxURBAq4sA%2FUeqSUh%2BF2afYWmALv10Yd6FWxBM8DFvvbDWicgXFT9HkFqzjeE5Tq4Lgr9e6G%2FX3PK7hktST1tkbPYLNmEm2npFTYza%2FqP5KProoaKGWqirW9PDhYinKW5bsa6jqDxS1Nlpnd1axvYMUrrh8OURAcynFE9%2FlA8i7F2sDchHjSHeIJ3s9vzH3vWPet%2Bb3Vm127L2w%2FTvkI%2BE66dfOTP4tr28fAObPuY9jP%2FS1t%2B2Pa%2Fsu0SDeQThPPZVje71zZ1rPdyDF%2F%2FBQ%3D%3D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One ionic app can launch another through the InAppBrowser, for instance. Or socialsharing plugin, etc. And then you need to pass on variables through the launch code. And then going back again.

But the UI experience will be awefull this way if functionally the apps actually are quite similar/related/dependent. So from a UI perspective not a very nice thing to do.

So basically, if you manage the code for all these apps, you may be better off integrating as modules/components in one code base.  If you don't own the other apps, make sure the UI is smooth.

Regards

Tom